# My Android React Native app gets killed at night

Tags: android, react-native

Our React Native app starts a foreground service + sticky notification to track the user's location. Last night it stopped unexpectedly and I do not know why. I can still see the notification, but the updating of the location has stopped.

Seems to me that the React Native service of the app is stopped and the foreground service is still running.

I made a bug report using developer settings and I think this is the relevant part (also in terms of timestamps):

```
  package: com.myapp.mobile
    Historical Process Exit for uid=10549
        ApplicationExitInfo #0:
          timestamp=2023-10-05 01:05:58.005 pid=8310 realUid=10549 packageUid=10549 definingUid=10549 user=0
          process=com.myapp.mobile reason=10 (USER REQUESTED) subreason=21 (FORCE STOP) status=0
          importance=125 pss=231MB rss=209MB description=stop com.google.android.webview due to installPackageLI state=empty trace=null
        ApplicationExitInfo #1:
          timestamp=2023-10-04 20:20:05.759 pid=8440 realUid=99256 packageUid=10549 definingUid=10171 user=0
          process=com.google.android.webview:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:0 reason=13 (OTHER KILLS BY SYSTEM) subreason=17 (ISOLATED NOT NEEDED) status=0
          importance=300 pss=53MB rss=143MB description=isolated not needed state=empty trace=null
```

It seems to me that Android is updating com.google.android.webview and with that stopping my precious app (thank you google).

Is there a way to work around this issue? Or maybe even a clean solution?

Comment: Hi there, have you found a solution to stop that background update of webview?

Comment: Sadly. I did not find a solution.